# How to obtain "diligence" from crossword clue "horse-drawn vehicle industry"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Cryptic clue: *Horse-drawn vehicle industry*

Answer: *Diligence*

How do we figure this one out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diligence) says:

> **diligence** (plural **diligences**)
>
> 1. conscientiousness or determination or perseverance when doing something
> 2. *(religion)* One of the seven contrary virtues, opposite the vice of sloth.
> 3. A public stage-coach. (19th century, now used only in reference to France or other European countries including Great Britain.)

*industry* (in the sense of "busily working") would match definition 1, and definition 3 is a horse-drawn vehicle, if an obscure one.  I had no idea!

Comment: wow.  i didnt find this where i usually look. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diligent. Good one. I expected it to be something on "vehicle industry", and not "h-d vehicle; industry" as two clues.

Comment: @JoseK: you'd find it if you searched for "diligence"!

Comment: @Jimi: but i did that too. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diligence

Comment: @JoseK: if you look at definition #2, it says "a large stage-coach", which is basically a horse-drawn carriage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=diligence&searchmode=none) of the third meaning given at the Wiktionary.

> From the secondary French sense comes the old usage of diligence for "public stage coach" (1742; dilly for short), from a French shortening of *carrosse de diligence*.

O.Fr. *diligence* means "attention, care; haste, speed," so *carrosse de diligence* means "speedy coach."

The [Encylopaedia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/163540/diligence) expands on how the *diligence* differs from the american stagecoach.

Comment: It amuses me that in 100 years we'll be similarly mystified by such words as *cassette* (what does that have to do with music?) and perchance *newspaper* (news was printed on paper??)